# broswerSnyc doesn't work on multiple device

Tags: javascript, gulp, workflow, browser-sync

Any thought why I only can make browserSync to work in one device? I tried to open the same address using another device, the URL is not accessible.

Comment: Can you share which devices you are using and your gulp file?

Answer (score 0):

Once you start the command you should have an output like:

```
[BS] Proxying: site.local
[BS] Access URLs:
-------------------------------------
    Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.10:3000
```

In your remote devices you should use the **External URL** such as: `http://192.168.0.10:3000` instead of the local URL.